# How to change text layer in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, gimpfu

I have a gimp file that I'm using as a template.

I'm trying to find a way to script something so that I can easily replace the template text in that file to something that I specify.

Cheers

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @xenoid see the second line in my question.. I need a way to script in gimp so that I change the text in a text layer

Comment: Yes, but where one should start? Do you know the Gimp API? Python? Scheme? Have you ever coded?

Comment: I've made scripts in various languages before. (Never really learned them, just learn as i go and lots of stack overflow). I've already looked up for multiple ways of doing this, and it doesn't seem like there are that many options. (Many ways like script fu don't seem to have a good api for text layer changing)

Answer (score 2):

To get you started:

The information of a text layer (text, fonts and other options) is kept in a "parasite". This "parasite" is created when the image is saved (no such parasite on a freshly created text layer). It can be retrieved and the information reused. IMHO it will be easier to recreate a new layer anyway. In Python:

```
def text_info(img,layer):
    parasites=None
    try:
        parasites=layer.parasite_list()
    except Exception as e:
        pass;
    if parasites and 'gimp-text-layer' in parasites:
        data=layer.parasite_find('gimp-text-layer').data
        pdb.gimp_message('Text layer "%s": %s' % (layer.name,data))
    else:
        pdb.gimp_message('No text information found for layer "%s"' % layer.name)
```

Code lifted from the `text-info` script/plugin that you'll find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)

[image]

```
Text layer "TEXT ...": (text "TEXT\nEXAMPLE")
(font "Roboto Heavy")
(font-size 60)
(font-size-unit pixels)
(antialias yes)
(language "en")
(base-direction ltr)
(color (color-rgb 0 0 0))
(justify center)
(box-mode dynamic)
(box-unit pixels)
(hinting yes)
```