# Changing content of an image by script

Tags: gimp

In a project we use GIMP to create banners (which are saved in the GIMP native format). All the work is done by humans. But it is often tedious work which consists of replacing one logo with an other logo with the same dimensions or one piece of text with an other piece of text. Sometimes many 100 times.

What is the best way to automatically replace an image (with the same dimensions) or a text in a GIMP file? Does it make more sense to script it within GIMP or is it better to do open heard surgery on the file itself without GIMP? Or is there a command line tool which I can use for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370256/how-to-change-text-layer-in-gimp

Comment: Depends a lot on the actual workflow. In an ideal world, you create the text/logo separately and export it as a "flat" type (PNG). Then you can use a command line tool such as [ImageMagick `composite`](https://imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) to overlay that image over as many other images as you want.